# Scraping house price using html tags instead of regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping house data such as price, number of bedrooms, distance from station etc from [zoopla.co.uk](https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine)

I was able to scrape the first two variables `bedrooms` and `bathrooms` as plain strings just by using `find()` and html tags. Regex not required.

I tried to do the same with the other three variables `house_price`, `house_type`, and `station_distance`, but I couldn't do it without using regex matching since the target text is surrounded by other text like the pound currency symbol`£` and other characters.

Those three regex'd variables return python lists therefore I have to subscript the lists to scrape the plain string out. e.g. `house_price = house_price[0]`,   `house_type = house_type[0]`, `station_distance = station_distance[0]`

Referring to the sample html, it shows:

1. `<a class="listing-results-price text-price" href="/for-sale/details/55920397"> £75,000`
2. `<h2 class="listing-results-attr"> <a href="/for-sale/details/55920397" style="text-decoration:underline;">1 bed flat for sale</a>`
3. `<li class="clearfix"> <span class="interface nearby_stations_schools_national_rail_station" title="Erdington"></span> <span class="nearby_stations_schools_name" title="Erdington">Erdington</span>(0.9 miles)</li>`

Is it possible to get the text for my three variables `house_price`, `house_type`, and `station_distance` variables without using regex and subscripting? Or is my solution the only solution?

Thanks

Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

my_url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine'
res = requests.get(my_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
lis = soup.find("ul", class_="listing-results clearfix js-gtm-list").find_all("li", class_="srp clearfix")

for li in lis:
    bedrooms = li.find("span", class_="num-beds")
    bathrooms = li.find("span", class_="num-baths")

    price = li.find("a", class_="text-price")
    house_price = re.findall('\£(\d+)', str(price))

    style = li.find("h2", class_="listing-results-attr")
    house_type = re.findall('(?<=bed ).*(?= for)', str(style))

    distance = li.find("li", class_="clearfix")
    station_distance = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', str(distance))

    if bedrooms:
        bedrooms = bedrooms.get_text(strip=True)
    if bathrooms:
        bathrooms = bathrooms.get_text(strip=True)
    if house_price:
        house_price = house_price[0]
    if house_type:
        house_type = house_type[0]
    if station_distance:
        station_distance = station_distance[0]

    df = pd.DataFrame({'house_price': house_price, 'house_type': house_type, 'station_distance': station_distance, 'bedrooms': bedrooms, 'bathrooms': bathrooms})
    print(df)

    df.to_csv('zoopla.csv')
```

Output

```
    house_price house_type         station_distance bedrooms    bathrooms
0   75          flat               0.9              1           1
1   90          flat               0.2              1           1
2   210         detached house     0.6              3           None
3   160         end terrace house  0.7              2           1
4   325         detached house     1.2              4           1
```

Sample object

```
<li class="srp clearfix" data-listing-id="55920397" id="listing_55920397">
<div class="listing-results-wrapper">
<div class="listing-results-left">
<div class="status-wrapper">
<a class="photo-hover" href="/for-sale/details/55920397">
<img alt="Thumbnail 1 bed flat for sale in Turfpits Lane, Erdington, Birmingham, West Midlands" class="lazy" data-ajax="55920397" data-src="https://lid.zoocdn.com/354/255/616d58ef5f9b23f949de3d6d183c8a6bef55757e.jpg"/>
<noscript><img alt="Thumbnail 1 bed flat for sale in Turfpits Lane, Erdington, Birmingham, West Midlands" src="https://lid.zoocdn.com/354/255/616d58ef5f9b23f949de3d6d183c8a6bef55757e.jpg"/></noscript>
</a>
<a href="/for-sale/details/55920397">
</a>
<div class="btn-photo-movie">
<a href="/for-sale/details/55920397"><i class="icon icon-camera"></i> 7</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="listing-results-right clearfix">
<div class="agent_logo">
<img alt="Marketed by Dixons Estate Agents - Erdington Sales" class="lazy" data-src="https://st.zoocdn.com/zoopla_static_agent_logo_(640108).png"/>
<noscript><img alt="Marketed by Dixons Estate Agents - Erdington Sales" src="https://st.zoocdn.com/zoopla_static_agent_logo_(640108).png"/></noscript>
</div>
<a class="listing-results-price text-price" href="/for-sale/details/55920397">
   
        £75,000    

                <span class="price-modifier">Offers over</span>
</a>
<h3 class="listing-results-attr">
<span class="num-icon num-beds" title="1 bedroom"><span class="interface"></span>1</span> <span class="num-icon num-baths" title="1 bathroom"><span class="interface"></span>1</span> <span class="num-icon num-reception" title="1 reception room"><span class="interface"></span>1</span>
</h3>
<h2 class="listing-results-attr">
<a href="/for-sale/details/55920397" style="text-decoration:underline;">1 bed flat for sale</a>
<span class="listing-results-just-added">Just added</span>
</h2>
<span><a class="listing-results-address" href="/for-sale/details/55920397">Turfpits Lane, Erdington, Birmingham, West Midlands B23</a></span>
<div class="listing-results-attr">
</div>
<p>

                    **Affordable housing** **80% shared ownership** **No rent required on the 20% share**Dixons are proud to present this one bedroom flat in Erdington perfect for first time buyers. Accommodation briefly comprises; open plan lounge/kitchen, one bedroom ...

                </p>
<div class="nearby_stations_schools clearfix">
<ul>
<li class="clearfix">
<span class="interface nearby_stations_schools_national_rail_station" title="Erdington"></span>
<span class="nearby_stations_schools_name" title="Erdington">Erdington</span>


            (0.9 miles)

        </li>
<li class="clearfix">
<span class="interface nearby_stations_schools_national_rail_station" title="Chester Road"></span>
<span class="nearby_stations_schools_name" title="Chester Road">Chester Road</span>


            (1.2 miles)

        </li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;">
<small>Note: Distances are straight line measurements</small>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="listing-results-footer clearfix">
<div class="listing-results-left">
<p class="top-half listing-results-marketed">
<small>
                                Listed on 
17th Aug 2020


                            by
                    </small><br/>
<span>Dixons Estate Agents - Erdington Sales, B23</span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="listing-results-right">
<p class="noprint list-inline actions compress">
<span class="agent_phone">
<a data-ga-action="Call" data-ga-category="Lead single (for-sale)" data-ga-label="/tracking/for-sale/results//28269" href="tel:+441216596496">
<i class="icon icon-phone"></i><span>+44 121 659 6496</span></a> **
                    </span>
<a data-ga-action="Contact agent" data-ga-category="Lead single for-sale" data-ga-label="/tracking/for-sale/results/" href="/for-sale/contact/55920397">
<i class="icon icon-mail"></i>Contact
                    </a>
<a class="link-novisit favourite-icon" data-ga-action="Click" data-ga-category="Save to Favourites" data-ga-label="Started" data-taxonomy='{"listings_category":"residential","action":"favourite_listing","section":"for-sale","activity":"user_account"}' data-title="Save property" href="/myaccount/favourites/listings/add/55920397">
<i class="icon icon-star"></i>
<span>Save</span></a>
<a class="" data-ga-action="Hide" data-ga-category="Hidden listings" data-ga-label="/tracking/for-sale/results/" data-hidden="false" data-listing-id="55920397" data-section="for-sale" data-taxonomy='{"listings_category":"residential","action":"hide_listing","section":"for-sale","activity":"user_account"}' data-title="Hide property" href="/myaccount/hidden-listings/hide/55920397?section=for-sale&amp;redirect=%2Ffor-sale%2Fproperty%2Fb23%2F%3Fpage_size%3D25%26q%3DB23%26radius%3D0%26results_sort%3Dnewest_listings%26search_source%3Drefine%26pn%3D1%26view_type%3Dlist" rel="nofollow"><i class="icon icon-block"></i><span class="js-hide-listing-copy" data-hide-copy="Hide" data-unhide-copy="Unhide">Hide</span></a>
</p>
</div>
</div> <!-- listing-results-footer -->
</div> <!-- listing-results-wrapper -->
</li>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the regex approach but you can use XPath (lxml) to achieve similar results.

Comment: Thanks Vektor. First time I've heard about XPath so I just googled it. But it seems regex is the convention over XPath right? Any advantages with XPath? Anyway, I'm new to bs4 so I wanted to know if my implementation is the convention and is also safe. It's normal to mix find() with separate regex queries? Should I roll with this implementation?

Comment: Just read a Medium piece about XPath. Seems similar to regex as you said. If I wanted to get the price text and exclude everything but the price decimal value, I would still end up having to write an expression so it seems like it's apples to oranges. It does seem a bit more 'modern' though so I will experiment with it :) Thanks.

Comment: Recently lxml seems to be the most popular option when parsing HTML data in Python, I believe it parses the HTML much faster too and XPath will do the searching and customizations all in one query.